# AngularJS evaluate $rootScope variable in directive template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a directive that creates an input field. 
I need to set the ng-model attribute of this input field to the value of a $rootScope
variable. 
The reason behind this is that I want the input field to be in the layout, and bind to different models depending on what page is loaded. 
I thought I'd set this global variable in each controller and access it in the Directive.

ATM the variable is hard coded

```
App.run(function($rootScope){
    $rootScope.mymodel = 'search.name';
})
```

And the Directive

```
Directives.directive('inputFilter', function(){
    return{
        restrict: 'E',
        replace:true,
        controller: function($scope, $rootScope){
            console.log($scope.mymodel);
            console.log($rootScope.mymodel)

        },
        template: '<input class="filter" type="text" ng-model="mymodel" placeholder="Nach filtern">'
    }

});
```

It gets rendered as

```
<input class="filter ng-pristine ng-valid" type="text" ng-model="mymodel" placeholder="Filter">
```

and the text inside the input field is the value of mymodel variable. The console.log shows

```
search.name
search.name
```

Could anyone please shed some light on this issue?

Comment: Might also have a look at referencing $root in your template which holds a reference to $rootScope in directives that have their own scope.  See - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22216441/what-is-the-difference-between-scope-root-and-rootscope

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What I think you want is

```
template: '<input class="filter" type="text" ng-model="' 
  + $rootScope.mymodel + '" placeholder="Nach filtern">'
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/ZavXw/).

Note that you will need to inject `$rootScope` into your directive:

```
Directives.directive('inputFilter', function($rootScope) {
```

Comment: any idea why the variable value is shown if i change the template like this? http://jsfiddle.net/ZavXw/1/

Comment: what is the difference between ng-model="{{mymodel}}" and placeholder="{{mymodel}}"

Comment: 1. Your fiddle: {{}} tells Angular to interpolate the value.  Since your controller scope prototypically inherits from $rootScope, Angular replaces `{{mymodel}}` with the interpolated value of `search.name`.
2. You can't use {{}}s inside ng-model because Angular will not interpolate ng-model values.  The ng-model value must be an (assignable) angular expression.  (Similarly, ng-click's value can't contain {{}}s either -- it also has to be an Angular expression).  The value of placeholder can contain {{}}s because the Angular compiler will notice it and interpolate it.

Comment: @glasspill, so the simple rule is:  if the Angular documentation says something needs an Angular expression, we can't use {{}}s there.  In our HTML (and templates) we can use {{}} (as long as it is not somewhere Angular wants to see an Angular expression) and Angular will do the interpolation magic.

Comment: Thank you, this was very frustrating and confusing

Comment: but why it's not work in placeholder like:

`template: '<input class="filter" type="text" ng-model="' 
  + $rootScope.mymodel + '" placeholder="{{$rootScope.mymodel}}">'`