# Accessing $rootScope variable from a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, scope, angularjs-scope

So I have a directive that look like this:

```
(function (module) {

    var node = function (RecursionHelper) {

        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            controller: 'mainController',
            scope: {
                node: '=n'
            },
            templateUrl: '/app/NSviewer/templates/parts/node.html',
            compile: function (element) {
                // Use the compile function from the RecursionHelper,
                // And return the linking function(s) which it returns
                return RecursionHelper.compile(element);
            }
        };

    };

    module.directive("node", node);


}(angular.module("anbud")));
```

And I have a layout variable that is defined like this:

```
$rootScope.layout = "test";
```

In the node directive. The layout variable is not displayed.

```
<pre>{{layout | json}}</pre>
```

This shows up as empty.

How can I access $rootScope.layout from my node directive?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS evaluate $rootScope variable in directive template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15434264/angularjs-evaluate-rootscope-variable-in-directive-template)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way:

```
<pre>{{$root.layout | json}}</pre>
```

Comment: That was easy :) Why isn't $rootScope.layout?

Comment: @ganjan because you have isolated scope in directive.

Answer (score 2):

Hi you need to inject `$rootScope` in your directive and try it this way:

```
{{$root.layout | json}}
```